# Is there any way to find the destination url of google map's shortned link and extract latitude and longitude with google apps script?

Tags: google-maps, redirect, google-apps-script, coordinates, short-url

I tried this:

```
function getCords() {//this function will extract coordinates from url
 url = <"short url getting from google map app in mobile">

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {followRedirects: false})
 var longUrl = decodeURIComponent(response.getHeaders()['Location'])
 var matches = longUrl.match(/!3d([\-]?[0-9]*.[0-9]*)\!4d([\-]?[0-9]*.[0-9]*)/)
 Logger.log(longUrl)

 var lat = matches[1]
 var lng = matches[2]

 Logger.log("Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lng)
 }
```

this is working for most of the links but some of the redirecting links not working.
for exemple:

`https://maps.app.goo.gl/nkGyxKo1fr6nMWS57`

It returns:
`https://www.google.com/maps/place//data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3b0871c9e03c4297:0x8ab1ea0cc97f9aab?utm_source=mstt_1`

It does not contain latitude and longitude values.
I also tried changing `{followRedirects: false}` to `{followRedirects: true}`. But not worked.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: How are you getting the url from the app?

Comment: @Pagemag When sharing the location we will get the url. You can test it by sharing it to clipboard and paste somewhere.